# How to see what is printed in eclipse? Java

Tags: java, eclipse

```
    class hello{
        public static void main(String[] arguments){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        System.out.println("New Line.");
    }
}
```

Above is my code and eclipse runs it without error report. It should print out Hello World! and New Line., but how can I see these content? I can't find it in eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your class `public`. It's not running it because it's not public.

Do a Window -> Show View -> Console and you should be able to see it.

Comment: It gives me something like this:

Comment: Usage: javaw [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  javaw [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client   to select the "client" VM
    -server   to select the "server" VM

Comment: But I didn't see any things that I want it to print.

Comment: Its not running your application - the java configuration in your Eclipse project isn't correct

Comment: Then how to fix it? I'm new to java.

Comment: You should accept some of your previous answers to encourage people to help you.

Comment: How do you run it exactly? You should do a right-click Run As -> Java Application. And you should check your Window -> Preferences -> Java -> INstalled JREs and make you are pointed to a valid Java installation.

Comment: It says "none applicable". For the JREs, it is jre6, Standard VM.